# spseg- Reardon and O'Sullivan's spatial segregation package

Tags: stata, spatial

Does anyone know if the `spseg` command was ever implemented in Stata? I was reading Reardon and O’Sullivan (2004) paper and came across a [PowerPoint lecture](https://www.stata.com/meeting/italy09/italy09_pisati.pdf) where Maurizio Pisati describes the `spseg` command in Stata. I tried to implement it, but it doesn't seem to exist in Stata and there isn't  any documentation on it. I know that R has a similarly named package, but was wondering if the package was ever implemented in Stata. I’d prefer to use the Stata package, if that’s available.

Comment: `search spseg` in Stata yields nothing. The natural line of enquiry is to email Sean Reardon and Maurizio Pisati for information. Their addresses are easy to find.

Comment: Yep did that as well, but posted here to cast a wider net in case anyone had any other ideas. They just emailed me now and said the package was never developed. Would appreciate it if there are any other Stata alternatives. If not, it looks R is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: According to Maurizio Pisati, it was never implemented.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears that the program in question was never written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Maurizio Pisati, it was never implemented.